# Finding and displaying contact in AB with its UID

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, abaddressbook

I'm having a problem understanding how to find a contact in the Mac Address Book and displaying it in the AB using the selectInAddressBook:sender method. The ABPeoplePicker CLass documentation doesn't mention precisely which information it passes to get the contact.

My context is an app where I would not select the contact from the PeopleViewer but by having a ABRecord UID previously stored in a database (for example: 6B2B9B69-CFC4-46F2-AEB1-43A99382D305:ABPerson). How can I use this info to reach the contact with the selectInAddressBook method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution in ABAddressBook.h in the address book framework.

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addressbook://%@",[aPerson uniqueId]];
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```